# Viewpager optimization with custom views

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-custom-view

**Scenario -** I am working on an app that shows events respective to particular dates in a viewpager, where each page represents a day(i.e 24 hrs in a vertical manner, similar to google calendar). Each page/fragment contains a vertical scrollview(it has a framelayout inside it) and based on list of events i am dynamically creating custom-views(view position and dimension is based on the corresponding event timing and duration) and adding it to the scrollview. **User can drag and drop events between dates.**

**Issue -** I have successfully achieved the view creation part, now the issue is with performance. Sometimes vewpager(using FragmentStatePagerAdapter) lags while swiping through pages.

Someone please suggest me how to reduce the lag or any better ways to achieve this

Comment: Have you tried using viewpager2 ?

Comment: Any particular clues why it could be better with viewpger2 ?

Comment: Because view pager 2 just like recycler view, it recycles the views so it makes a lot of difference and you can use all the features available with Recycler view like Diffutils.

Comment: It's hard to help you without your code. The problem could be very different. To big images, shadows, animations ect...

Comment: Sorry for not able to provide any code, but what I am doing is simply 1. create a custom-view that draws hour lines(i.e 24 lines for each hour, it will create the background) in canvas and add it in the framelayout 2. Then creating N (number of events) views(inflating a layout and assigning layout-params) and add it to the framelayout,,,,,,,,,for reference check google calendar(day view), Kindly suggest any good approach to solve this, I think the lag is because of step 2

Answer (score 0):

Yes I had a similar performance with viewpager and FragmentStatePagerAdapter, the problem with viewpager is that pre creates the views either side of the current view to speed up the swipe to next view.

This works well for static views but for views with dynamic data the pre-created view was usually out of date and needed to be regenerated when the user swiped to it.

Thus it was having to call `onCreateView` on 3 views while the user swiped between views leading to lag sometimes.

I thought of 2 improvements for performance, though only used one.

1) The view holder/model pattern e.g. https://www.androidcode.ninja/android-viewholder-pattern-example/ and https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel where the inflation and finding items re-used / separated from `onCreateView` activities.

I did not use this method

2) Create bare bones views for the dynamic ones (The first view was static and then there were 2 dynamic ones at positions 1 and 2 that contained listviews of different aspects of the dynamic data.)

The listviews were inflated and had an adapter set to an empty list in `onCreateView` of these views thus they were fast to create.

Then I added an on `OnPageChangeListener` which notified the `adapter` backing the `ViewPager` that the pages had changed

```java
        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                if (position == 1 || position == 2)
                {
                    mSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                // Code goes here
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                // Code goes here
            }
        });
```

The `notifyDataSetChanged` causes the viewPager to call `getItemPosition` in the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` class to work out if the page position has changed and it if need to re-create it in the a new position.

Then in `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` extended class I overrode `getItemPosition` with

```java
@Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            if (object instanceof LogFragment) {
                LogFragment f = (LogFragment) object;
                if (f != null) {
                    f.update();
                }
            } else if (object instanceof SummaryFragment){
                SummaryFragment f = (SummaryFragment) object;
                if (f != null) {
                    f.update();
                }
            } else {
                return POSITION_UNCHANGED;
            }
            return super.getItemPosition(object);
        }
```

This allowed me to get the Fragment object and then call the `update` method on it but still returning `POSITION_UNCHANGED` so the viewpager did not try and re-create the Fragments.

Then in the `update` method of the Fragment I get the listview adapter and update the data.

```java
public void update(){
        adapter.clear();
        adapter.addAll(datasource.getData());
    }
```

Thus the more costly getting and display the dynamic data is only done when the page is actually display, NOT when it is pre-created by viewPager (because that pre-created view would be old out of date data anyway and would need to be updated)

There is one downside to this approach, the screen shown **during** the swipe is still the old data (either empty or data from when that page was last updated), this was acceptable to me.